# MongoDb loses performance in Windows Server 2012

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2012

I am running an application how reads and write a batch process using MongoDb in 2 identical machines. One running Windows 8.1 and the other running Windows Server 2012.

The MongoDb performance in the Windows Server 2012 machine is 5 times worse than Windows 8.
   Both machines have 16Gb of RAM, but the mongod.exe process consumes 1.2Gb RAM in Windows 8 and 500Mb in Windows server in an identical local database.

I already use MongoDb 2.4, 2.6 and 2.6 legacy and de behavior is the same.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: What are you comparing -- Windows 8 versus Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8.1 versus Windows Server 2012? You use both in the question. Windows Server 2012 is the server equivalent of Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 R2 is the server equivalent of Windows 8.1.

Comment: Where are the RAM numbers coming from? Can you post the command and the exact output? 5 times worse performance is in terms of time?

Comment: I'm comparing the MongoDb performance in 2 machines with the same hardware. The only difference is OS. The first is Windows 8.1 64bits and the second Windows Server 2012 R2 64bits. The process results are very differents in terms of time. I already observe the same behavior using Windows 7, but now a need to solve it.

Comment: 5 times in terms of time. The RAM numbers are the MongoDb Working Set in the Task Manager.

Comment: @JoãoKracik: Please show us the code you are using for measuring, the data model. Also, how did you insert the test data for each run? How many rounds did you try? Please be more specific so that we can help you to find out what is going on?